# Need help structuring React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

I am designing/creating an application in React, but I need some help structuring the whole thing.

The app I want to create is built as follows:
[image]

Now, I have a couple questions about how to structure this, and what react plugins or frameworks come in handy:

1. Should the "filter" bar be part of the main layout ("master page")?
2. I assume [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) is a good choice for routing in react?
3. When working with data (both displaying and manipulating), is [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) a good thing to work with? Or has Flux nothing to do with data?
4. I'd retrieve my data from an ASP.Net WebAPI. Is this something I'd typically do with "plain" XmlHttpRequest / jquery ajax? Or is there a more "React"-way?
5. Extra: is there a specific reason to use *Redux*? I really don't understand the use of that :)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: 1. It should be in a Navbar component.
2. Even though react-router is a good choice you have other alternatives that you may check out.
3. I don't know that much flux, you should probably read their GitHub docs.
4. You can make an $.get when componentDidMount since React has 'callbacks' for components when they do certain type of things.
5. Redux is a reducer that describe how state changes, it's more advanced, but you can also read about it, if you're getting started it may seem complicated..

Comment: What if the filter values should be passed through navigation? For example, this could be a "year" filter which filters the current data shown? Do i use Context for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can have a layout like this:

```
<App>
    <Navbar /> { /* Here you show the username also, this view will depend on props */ }
    <Layout /> { /* Here you may have the content and the sidenav */ }
</App>
```

App is the top component, the main container that passes props for example in the render() you will have

```
// You should treat this as a Page component, the one that grabs
// data and passes it as props to another components
export default class AppPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<AppLayout { ...this.props } />);
    }
}

export default class AppLayout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar someProp={ this.props.someProp } />
            { this.props.children }
        );
    }
}
```

Router can be for example:

```
<Router history={ browserHistory }>
  <Route path="/" component={ App }>
    <IndexRoute component={ Landing } />
    <Route path="/index" component={ Layout } />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

The IndexRoute is '/' and you can say which components should be used on which route, for example if you route to /layout { this.props. children } on AppLayout will render as the `<Layout />` component.

I suggest you read this article: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html
to better understand how react works... Hope it helped

Comment: Thank you for the link. Made the basic principles (props, state) quite a bit clearer...